# arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() for multiple workspaces

Tags: python, gis, arcpy

I'm trying to use arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() for multiple workspaces within the same script. Looking through other example scripts, I thought I could simply assign workspaces to a variable, and then use that variable within arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for example:

```
workspace = "C:\\location\\"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(workspace)
for fc in fcs:
    print fc
```

but this results in an error:

```
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I've gotten arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() to work when I'm only interested in the feature classes within the default workspace, like:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\location\\"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

But I'm interested in looking through different folders for each step of my script, and I don't want reset my default workspace for each step.

Furthermore, why have I seen the first example used in other people's scripts (including those of my GIS programming professor) and they seemed to work in those instances, but I get an error.

Thank you for any help or advice that can be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example will certainly not work. `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` takes 3 optional arguments and the workspace isn't part of them, it must be defined beforehand, see the [Help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/ListFeatureClasses/03q300000023000000/) of the function for the exact syntax.

Resetting the current workspace isn't such a big deal. Depending on the types of workspaces you work with (folder, geodatabase, SDE, various...) and how they are structured (are they all within the same location? Do you have a list of specific folders/databases?) you will first list them, then iterate over the workspaces to list their feature classes:

```
# 1. List workspaces

listWS = [r"C:\DATA", r"D:\PROJECT\geodatabase.gdb", r"D:\whatever.mdb"]
# use this if the workspaces are in various locations

# or: 

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\DATA"
listWS = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
# use this if the workspaces are in the same location

# 2. Iterate over the workspaces and list their feature classes

for ws is listWS:
 arcpy.env.workspace = ws
 listFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
 for fc in listFC:
  # do something
```

See the [Help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/ListWorkspaces/03q30000004z000000/) for `arcpy.ListWorkspaces()` to see how to restrict your list to certain types of workspaces or using a wildcard.